# Make react read a external variable defined outside the root component

Tags: reactjs

I have a bundled React application loaded into a HTML by a  tag. I would like to pass some initial data to this application and I would like to define this data in HTML or in some previously loaded javascript.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish that?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The react document have pretty clear example about this, see this [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

```
var PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Just notice that the variable must be loaded before calling to it, with correct scope.